# Find $a$ so that $f(x)\le1$

Tags: functions, inequality

> Let
>   $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
> x-a&x\le1\\ax-3&x>1
> \end{cases}\quad a\in\Bbb R$$
>   a) Find $a$ so that $f$ is injective.
>   b) Find $a$ so that $f$ is surjective.
>   c) *Find $a$ so that $f(x)\le1$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$.*

a) Since the function is increasing for $x\le1$, we also need the function to increase for $x>1$ and $ax-3\ge x-a$. So, we have the following conditions: 
$$a>0$$
$$a\ge\frac{x+3}{x+1}$$
From the second condition, since we are working on the branch with $x>1$, we get $a\ge2$.

b) We calculate the limits at the ends of the intervals $(-\infty,1]$ and $(1,\infty)$ and we get $(-\infty,1-a]\cup(a-3,\infty)$. Since $f$ must be surjective, we must have $1-a\ge a-3$, and we get $a\in(0,2]$.

c) I don't know how to solve this. I tried to consider two cases for each, as in the function, but got nowhere.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For part $c)$, what happens if $a$ is negative and $x$ is $1$?  Is $f(x)\leq 1$?  What happens if $a$ is positive and $x\to\infty$?  Is $f(x)\leq 1$?  Are there any other choices for $a$?  Does that work?

Answer (score 1):

For $0<a<4$, $x=\frac4a+1$ makes $f(x)>1$, violating the question's condition $(*)$ that $f(x)\le1$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$:
$$f(x)=a\left(\frac4a+1\right)-3=4+a-3=1+a>1$$
For $a\ge4$, $(*)$ is violated because
$$f(2)=a\cdot2-3\ge4\cdot2-3=5>1$$
For $a<0$, $(*)$ is violated because
$$f(1)=1-a>1$$
Therefore $a$ can only be $0$:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x&x\le1\\-3&x>1
\end{cases}$$
It is easy to verify that this $f$ satisfies $(*)$.